# Como corresponder um valor de um array com outro valor em outro array no Java?

Tags: java, android, array, thread, arraylist

Eu sei como obter o valor de uma posição do array e comparar os valores do array. Conforme código abaixo.

```
for (int i = 0; i < listadosWifi.size(); i++) {
        /* pega o SSID e o BSSID */
        providerName = "\n"+(listadosWifi.get(i).SSID).toString()+ "\n"+(listadosWifi.get(i).level);
        listViwProvider = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view_wifi);
        listaFornecedores.add(providerName);
        t1.speak("Redes Disponíveis: " + providerName, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null, null);
        t1.setPitch(1);

            if (listadosWifi.get(i).level < -10 && listadosWifi.get(i).level > -50 ) {
                t1.speak("Você está próximo de: " + providerName, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, null);
                t1.setPitch(1);
                if(listadosWifi.get(i).level < -50){
                    t1.speak("Você está próximo de: " + providerName, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, null);
                    t1.setPitch(1);
                }
          }             
}
```

Agora eu quero corresponder 1 valor que está em 1 array com outro valor de outro array, mesmo que eles mudem de ordem. Pois quero fazer uma correspondência em tempo real. Como posso fazer isso e utilizar thread para atualizar periodicamente?

Comment: Você quer verificar  se cada elemento de uma array existe em outro, percorrendo todos os dois arrays?! É isso?

Comment: Não! É o seguinte, conforme mostrado no código, tenho um array que armazena o nome da rede e e outro array que armazena a força do sinal. Porém eu preciso pegar o primeiro valor do array (nomeWifi),(sinal), fazer a correspondência entre eles e fazer uma comparação com todos os outros valores em tempo real. Para que assim , usando a TTS, o app me fale em qual Wifi estou mais perto e quando me afastar do mesmo, o app diga que estou me afastando. Nisso , a rede que tiver o maior sinal irá passar pra posição do anterior?